# Reducing logfiles to just strings of interest

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I have logfiles containing strings of interest:

```
ANYTHING*"tested:/DD.MM.YY/directory/FILENAME:worked"ANYTHING*
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How could I select everything besides the strings of interest (including the `"`s) and delete it?

In the end, I *just* want lines with the strings of interest, reduced to *just* the strings of interest.

Comment: Is `worked"` always the end of the strings that interest you?  What about when testing a given file did *not* work?

Comment: Can `directory` and/or `FILENAME` contain spaces or other non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: :worked" is not always the end of the whole line but of the searched string, Filename could be anything (I thought about *)  directory could be more directorys it was just an example but for the regex it self /directory/ is fix

Comment: there are a lot of parameters in those lines and even lines I'm not interessted in which I want to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in the Notepad++ *Replace* dialog...

- *Find what:* `^(.*(tested:\/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}(\/[\w ]+)+\/[\w ]+:worked).*|.*(\r\n)?)$`
- *Replace with:* `\2`

...with the *Regular expression* checkbox checked under *Search Mode*.

Here is the start of a test with this in Notepad++:

[image: Start of Test]

And here is the end of the test after a series of *Find Next* and *Replace* actions:

[image: End of Test]

Comment: It doesn't work, even removing the ^ brings a count of 0 on those strings. I also tried to escape the : but doesn't change anything.

Comment: sorry My fault missed that \d means digit. But if there are blank lines in between other content doesn't get removed. thanks alot!

Comment: @user1735225: I updated my answer to account for blank lines.  Just *Find Next* and *Replace* until there are no more matches or just use *Replace All* once you are sure any remaining kinks are worked out for your needs.

Comment: thanks alot, is there a reason it doesn't work with online editors like regex101.com ? (maybe some kind of timeout?) I understand what you are doing inside of the (test:....:worked) but I don't understand how the outside stuff works even with the or...